# What does the error code 39 mean?

Tags: windows, dvd, norton-antivirus

What is code 39? I deleted Norton from my system and now my DVD won't play, system says it has been disabled.

I can't find where to enable it again. I keep getting a 39 code.

Comment: Try the Microsoft fixit tool...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060

Answer (score 1):

This guy had the same problem, and the fix presented to him seems to solve his problem:
[dell forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/disk-drives/f/3534/p/19242962/19373694.aspx)

Summarized:

> 1) Download and run the Sony BMG Uninstaller. (This will remove any
>   possible DRM installed when using Sony CDs)
>
> 2) Search for these 2 files using Windows Explorer (afs.sys or
>   afs2k.sys) and if found rename them by adding a 1 right before the
>   .sys (ex. afs1.sys). These are old Oak Technologies files that have
>   been found to conflict with cdrom.sys (the CD-ROM driver).

Also on [forums.techguy.org](http://forums.techguy.org/multimedia/639586-solved-dvd-cd-error-code.html) there's a fix presented.

Summzarized:

> To resolve this problem, remove the affected filter drivers. To do
>   this, follow these steps: Click Start, type regedit in the Start
>   Search box, and then click regedit in the Programs list.
>
> If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation,
>   type your password, or click Continue. Locate, and then click the
>   following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
>   Caution There can be many instances of the registry subkey that is
>   mentioned in step 2. You must make sure that you are in the
>   appropriate registry subkey before modifying the UpperFilters and the
>   LowerFilters values. To verify that you are in the appropriate
>   registry subkey, make sure that the Default data value is DVD/CD-ROM
>   and the Class data value is CDROM. In the right pane, if you have
>   UpperFilters, right-click UpperFilters, and then click Delete. Click
>   Yes to confirm the removal of the UpperFilters registry entry. In the
>   right pane, if you have LowerFilters, right-click LowerFilters, and
>   then click Delete. Click Yes to confirm the removal of the
>   LowerFilters registry entry. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart
>   the computer. Note After you remove the UpperFilters registry entry
>   and the LowerFilters registry entry, you may lose functionality in
>   certain programs such as CD recording programs. In this scenario, you
>   must reinstall any affected programs. If the problem recurs, contact
>   the program vendor to determine whether an update is available for the
>   program.

I haven't done these steps, so I don't know if they are valid. The first one is a marked answer and the second one is from a website I often visit, so I think the info is valid.

Comment: Can you summarize here instead of just dropping links to other sites?  Answers that consist solely of links are discouraged unless the content is just too long or complex to put here (and IMO this isn't).

Comment: Upvoted after the edit, thanks.  (I can also confirm that at least the second technique can work - I see iTunes do that same thing a lot, actually, and that fixes it.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you eventually play dvd with VLC media player from http://videolan.org/ ?

It is either a solution as it might as well play DVD, or gives much more info on what went wrong.

Have you ever tinkered with RPC-1? If yes it might have gone wrong badly.

It would be of value to have first and "system" screens using [a free DVD info tool](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/inspector/inspector.php) posted here too.